Tanstack Query + useEffect
This code is working weirdly for useQuery. Apparently on the first button click useQuery will not get the updated value of count while the fetcher function gets the updated value (1). I observed that if you move the useEffect below the useQuery function it works fine.  Putting the refetch in the dependency array requires putting the useEffect below the useQuery function.
Edits:
Updated code and added
codesandbox.io
Please check out the console logs when executing the button for just 1 time.
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

function Comp() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (count > 0) {
      fetcher();
      refetch();
    }
  }, [count]);

  const { refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["count", count],
    queryFn: async () => {
      console.log(`useQuery called -> count=${count}`);

      if (count === 0) {
        return "ignore";
      }

      const result = await fetch("...", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ count }),
      });

      if (!result.ok) {
        //throw new Error("Something went wrong");
      }

      return "ok";
    },
    enabled: false,
  });

  const fetcher = async () => {
    console.log(`Fetch called -> count=${count}`);

    if (count === 0) {
      return;
    }

    try {
      const result = await fetch("...", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ count }),
      });

      if (!result.ok) {
      }

      // do something the request didnt fail
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
        }}
      >
        Click
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Comp;

Any idea why useQuery works like that? Any idea how to approach this without using Redux etc.? Thanks.

Do fetcher and the useQuery function both fetch the same url? If so, what's the reason for having a separate fetcher function and calling it explicitly in an useEffect, instead of just using the query?

@NicholasTower Forget the url. What i am trying to show is the while these functions are getting called together one has the value of count=1 (fetcher func) and the other has count=0 (useQuery).

The useQuery's query function won't run at all because of enabled: false

@RoMilton
it will run by calling the refetch. It's a mechanism to prevent useQuery to run on component load. Say you want to run useQuery only on button click. You have to use enable:false and call the returned refetch function.
const { refetch } = useQuery({...})
I added a codesandbox and slightly modified the code. Please check the logs when running the app through the sandbox in the browser.

Apparently, useQuery updates its internal states via a useEffect. If you call refetch before then, refetch will look up the old version of the query function, which closes over the old count. When a component calls useEffect multiple times, they are executed in the order they are written so if you put your use effect before useQuery, then your useEffect runs first. Move it after the query, and the order will be correct.
PS: you mentioned in the comments that you're using this approach so that the fetch could be skipped on the first render. But it would still be unusual to manually call refetch in a useEffect. refetch is designed for being called in event handlers, like an onClick. If you want the refetch to be tied to the react lifecycle, the typical way to do this would be to set state, and let react query handle the rest.
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

const { data } = useQuery({
  queryKey: ["count", count],
  queryFn: async () => {
     // ...
  },
  enabled: count > 0, // <---- control when the query executes
});


enabled: count > 0 works! And it's more elegant and performant since i can avoid the useEffect. Thanks.
